# Add spaces after fullstops

Tags: python, string, nltk

I have a paragraph of sentences that I tokenize into separate sentences using `nltk`'s `sent_tokenize`. However, some sentences follow immediately after the fullstop `.` from the previous sentence. As such `sent_tokenize` doesn't seem to be able to differentiate the two sentences. For example:

`"Today I went for ice-cream.It was good."` when parsed with `sent_tokenize` still gives `"Today I went for ice-cream.It was good."`. On the other hand, `"Today I went for ice-cream. It was good."` when parsed with `sent_tokenize` gives `"Today I went for ice-cream."` and `"It was good."`

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a good reason that nltk works like that. What you want will tokenize sentences like "The U.S. is a country." into three sentences: "The U", "S", and "is a country". Unless you have a very good reason to do that, I would advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all occurrences of "." with ". " as here:

```
text = "Today I went for ice-cream.It was good."
text.replace(".", ". ")
```

Comment: thank you! that doesn’t work for me currently because some full stops will then have 2 spaces after them. i’ll find another way, thanks!